# Contingent Multi-thread, but Not Single-thread, Bug (Common Lisp)

Tags: multithreading, stack, common-lisp

I've narrowed a problem down to one particular function call to one of my library routines that looks like `(pop-hstack current-hstack)`, which pops an element from a stack structure. It is causing data corruption (an inconsistency, see below) in the stack structure, but only when multiple threads are running. I've tried wrapping  the call in a lock like so `(bt:with-lock-held (*lock*) (pop-hstack current-hstack)`, but current-hstack is still becoming inconsistent somewhere during execution when there are two or more threads active. The arguments to pop-hstack (eg, current-hstack) in each thread are dynamically bound special variables, and so are not shared between threads. It's confusing whether the inconsistency is being introduced by multi-threading (no inconsistency running single-thread), or perhaps by a contingent programming bug in the structure definition or pop-hstack function.

```
(defstruct hstack
  "An hstack (hash stack) is an expanded stack representation containing an
   adjustable one-dimensional array of elements, plus a hash table for quickly
   determining if an element is in the stack. Keyfn is applied to elements to
   access the hash table. New elements are pushed at the fill-pointer, and
   popped at the fill-pointer minus 1."
  (vector (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer t) :type (array * (*)))
  (table (make-hash-table) :type hash-table)  ;can take a custom hash table
  (keyfn #'identity :type function))  ;fn to get hash table key for an element

(defun pop-hstack (hstk)
  "Pops an element from hstack's vector. Also removes the element's index from
   the element's hash table entry--and the entry itself if it's the last index."
  (let* ((vec (hstack-vector hstk))
         (fptr-1 (1- (fill-pointer vec)))
         (tbl (hstack-table hstk))
         (key (funcall (hstack-keyfn hstk) (aref vec fptr-1))))
    (when (null (setf (gethash key tbl) (delete fptr-1 (gethash key tbl))))
      (remhash key tbl))
    (vector-pop vec)))
```

Normally, hstack's stack vector and hash table are in sync, containing the same number of entries: `(length (hstack-vector x)) = (hash-table-count (hstack-table x))`. Only when there are duplicate elements in hstack, will the number of entries differ. (Because then a single hash table entry will contain multiple vector indices for  duplicate elements appearing in the vector.) However, the inconsistency between the number of entries in the vector and the hash table still shows up when there are no duplicate elements. Typically, there are one or two extra elements in the hash table, indicating that these extra elements were not properly removed during a pop-hstack operation. The stack vector always seems to have the correct elements.

EDIT(5/2/19): Corrected a coding error in pop-hstack: Replace `(delete fptr-1 (gethash key tbl))` with `(setf (gethash key tbl) (delete fptr-1 (gethash key tbl)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `(delete fptr-1 (gethash key tbl))` might be the cause, it modifies the list structure so that concurrent access might see a corrupt list.

What's the definition of the `push` operation?
Does corruption also occur if all push and all pop operations are wrapped in `with-lock-held` (using the same lock)?

Comment: Thanks for slogging thru this. I think you must be right about `delete` corruption. Hash table access is protected by specifying a :synchronized table (in SBCL), but `delete` is still unprotected. I was originally thinking the lock around the entire function call would protect all operations internal to `pop-hstack`, but maybe this is not true. (Printing the hstack immediately before and immediately after popping shows up the corruption.)

Comment: In any event, I've since changed the hash table representation to only keep track of the number of elements in the stack for each key, instead of the actual index of each element like so: `(when (zerop (decf (gethash key tbl))) (remhash key tbl))`. Now there is no problem, although `decf` should probably now be replaced with `sb-ext:atomic-decf`. Thanks again for your insight.